# Deleting Running Jobs from Beanstalkd Queue in laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd

Here is the scenario, I'm using Beanstalkd queue to send an email to a huge list of emails (50000+), each email has to have some unique content so the fired job loops over all the addresses, generates the content and sends the mail.

Sometimes the user may want to cancel the operation in the middle of sending, so for example while the job is running and after the mail was sent to say 20000 addresses, the user clicks on "Stop" which should "delete" the job.

what I have done so far is that I managed to get the running job instance, Queue::Push returns the job ID, so I save this ID saved in DB, and when I want to stop the job this is what I tried to do

```
$phean= Queue::getPheanstalk();

$res = $phean->peek($Job_ID); // returns a Pheanstalk_Job
$job = new \Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob(app() , $phean, $res , 'default') ;

$res = $job->delete() // returns NOT_FOUND ??
$data = $job->getRawBody() // returns correct data, so I'm sure this is the right job instance
```

so why do I get NOT_FOUND, although when I use 
    supervisorctl tail -f queuename 
I can see that the job is still running and outputting content

Any help ? If there is a better approach than trying to get the job and delete it this way I'm open to suggestions, I thought about saving the job ID in database (ID , status), and when I want to delete it I alter the ID status, and In the loop that is running within the job it checks every time, or maybe every 10 times, and if the status is equal to 1 for example then $job->delete(), but this will be so slow as it will hit the db in every loop.

Comment: Your last option sounds about right, but I'd use the cache instead of the DB. And check every 100th iteration or so.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a a main job, which you `reserve()` and hold open, and in that job you create many emails directly.

**Since the job you are trying to delete is currently reserved, you can't delete it**. Even if you could, how would the currently running job be informed by Beanstalkd?

Instead, I would have the main loop check for any jobs on some separate control tube (you could do a quick check every say 10 or 100 emails sent) - just to request a new job, but not waiting if there isn't anything there. If there is a job there, then the main process cleans up and exits.

Another idea is not to actually send email in the main loop, but instead put the details of what emails to send, one per address, into the queue. Other processes read that mass-queue and start sending emails, but again, also read a control tube (with a higher priority message that would be returned ahead of the lower-priority email/details message). If there's anything in the control tube, stop sending emails. You would need at least as many STOP messages in the control tube as you have workers.